# Why does reading a file that doesn't exist print garbage characters?

Tags: c++, file

I try to understand the file reading in `c++` and try to read a file that doesn't exist deliberately

```
//includes ommited

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        if(argc != 1)
                throw std::exception();
        std::ifstream file(argv[0]);
        std::string content((std::istream_iterator<char>(file)), std::istream_iterator<char>());
        std::cout << content.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e0f5c0e090045f9)**

It prints the following:

```
ELF
```

Why is it supposed to mean? Do I just get UB by doing this? Since I'm a Java coder I expected that some exception will be thrown if we try to read a file that doesn't exist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv[0]` contains path to your executable.

> http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html
>
> The file name of the program being run is also included in the vector as the first element; the value of argc counts this element.

Just try to print it's contents:

```
std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
```

You probably want to use `argv[1]`.

"ELF" is the begin of file header of [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Comment: Ok, now it just prints nothing

Comment: Maybe because of your condition to throw an exception. That should also be the behavior in the first case.

Comment: @St.Antario You should pass an argument to your executable - just append it after `./a.out` on Coliru.